# Подключение единственного js-скрипта в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, как правильно подключить единственный скрипт в плагине?
Т.е. нужно сначала подключить ajax, а потом подключить скрипт, в котором нужно с помощью ajax сделать обращение к php-скрипту.
На какой хук правильно подключать?
И в документации говорится, что ajax нужно подключать после какого-то скрипта.
В данном случае перед ajax скрипты не подключаются. Нужно подключить только после установки ajax

Comment: "И в документации говорится, что ajax нужно подключать после какого-то скрипта." - прям так и говорится, какого-то?

И какое отношение скрипт в плагине имеет к аяксу?

Comment: "В данном случае перед ajax скрипты не подключаются. Нужно подключить только после установки ajax" - это как и зачем? Что значит установка ajax?

Comment: т.е. инициализация переменной ajaxurl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный способ подключения скрипта в плагине - только один: `wp_enqueue_script()`.

И на это не влияет ни наличие, ни отсутствие ajax, ни что-либо другое.